# How to dynamically create/modify sitemap.xml file in angular 9 project structure at runtime?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, sitemap, angular9

How to create dynamic sitemap.xml file in Angular 9 project structure ? I can get data using HTTP get request from node API but using this data how can I update local xml file from angular project at runtime ?

In my case, angular project and node project are on different server(different domain). And It is possible to create xml file in node project but I am not able to access that file as xml file in angular project root .

Can anyone please suggest me how to use node xml in angular project OR is it possible to create/modify dynamic sitemap.xml using api call in Angular 9?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on the same subject now and I have achieved something.

I added it in the `angular.json` file like this

[image: sitemap.xml]

Then I created a component and specified its path as `sitemap.xml`.

It is possible to perform server-side rendering in Angular, and with that, our job is a little easier. [Angular Server Side Rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

*You can add a new routing to your routing.module file and interfere with this request via `server.ts`*

For example, you can access a route like `sitemap.xml` in this way in `server.ts`.

```
server.get('/sitemap.xml', (req, res, next) => { bla,bla }
```

*You can now access the file you want here and change it as you wish.*

File operations in `server.ts`

```
function writeFile(sitemap: string): void {
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.appendFile('../sitemap.xml', sitemap, (err) => {
    if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
    console.log('Saved!');
  });
}
```

then, redirect operations

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:{$PORT}/sitemap.xml');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate more on that how did you added data into sitemap.xml which you pull from web service ? Can we modify sitemap.xml file which resides in assets folder ?

Comment: Yes this is correct way. But the problem is, to use server side rendering in angular I need nodeJS installation in my angular website server which is not possible in my case. Is there any way to achieve this without nodeJS installation ?

Comment: @muhammet Can you please provide workable example code?

Comment: @muhammed any chance you can provide demo code for this? Please

Comment: @Rahul Unfortunately I stopped working with Spartacus.